# deleted items subscription with rxjs

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs

Hi I'm using rxjs to manage a list of objects. What I want to do is to subscribe to a list of deleted object. I created a Subject object (deleted) where a put every object that a remove form Observable(listObject). I tried to subscribe to deleted but I think this is not a good idea because when i put an object on deleted stream I don't now if this object is on listObject stream. In the link above there a sample code

```
var newObject = new Rx.Subject();
    var deleteObject = new Rx.Subject();
    var create = new Rx.Subject();
    var updates = new Rx.Subject();
    var remove = new Rx.Subject();
    var listObject = updates.scan(
        function (objects, operation) {
            return operation(objects);
        }, []);

    create.map(function (object) {
            return (
                function (objects) {
                    return _.union(objects, [object]);
                }
            );
        })
        .subscribe(updates);

    remove.map(function (object) {
            return (
                function (objects) {
                    return _.without(objects, object);
                }
            );
        })
        .subscribe(updates);


    newObject.subscribe(create);
    deleteObject.subscribe(remove);
```

[Sample code](http://pastebin.com/nitbJfNi)

Edit1

If I subscribe to listObject I'll always be notified of all updates to the object list. In my idea I want to have an rx object to subscribe to get last deleted item from list, one to get last inserted item and one to get the list of all items

Comment: Marco, can you please put an example of input vs. expected output vs. actual output? Also if you could format properly your question, it would help. On SO you must paste your code instead/in addition to giving a link to it (I already pasted the code there). Rationale for that is that the link might become invalid at some point of time. Last thing, your `updates` is not subscribed to. So with this current code, you would not see much output.